# Multiple lines in make

Tags: makefile

I am trying to store a multiline string in a variable in make

```
var=$(shell cat <<End-of-message \
-------------------------------------\
This is line 1 of the message.\
This is line 2 of the message.\
This is line 3 of the message.\
This is line 4 of the message.\
This is the last line of the message.\
-------------------------------------\
End-of-message)


printit:
    @echo ${var}
```

This doesn't work, so I am wondering if this is possible at all. I need to preserve the newlines here and shell is converting them in spaces. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any reason you can't have the text you need to use in an external file vs. inside the makefile?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to create a multi-line string variable in a Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649246/is-it-possible-to-create-a-multi-line-string-variable-in-a-makefile)

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
define var
@echo -------------------------------------
@echo This is line 1 of the message.
@echo This is line 2 of the message.
@echo This is line 3 of the message.
@echo This is line 4 of the message.
@echo This is the last line of the message.
@echo -------------------------------------
endef

printit:
    ${var}
```

or this:

```
.PHONY: var
var:
    @echo -------------------------------------
    @echo This is line 1 of the message.
    @echo This is line 2 of the message.
    @echo This is line 3 of the message.
    @echo This is line 4 of the message.
    @echo This is the last line of the message.
    @echo -------------------------------------

printit: var
```