# Output multiline variable to a file with GNU Make

Tags: makefile

I'm having hard time writing a makefile rule that outputs a multiline variable in a file.

Here is the code I have :

```
define VAR1
    /dev d 755 - - - - -
endef

define VAR2
    /test d 777 - - - - -
    /test2 d 777 - - - - -
endef

VARS += $(VAR1)
VARS += $(VAR2)

all:
    echo "$(VARS)" > test
```

However, the echo fails telling "Unterminated quoted string" for a reason unknown to me.
How  could i put in the file every lines declared on a separate line ?

Comment: Commenting to link the two questions, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5887751/4238087) SO answer helped me out the most here and isn't in the answers on this question. Building in devtoolset-11 on EL7, the other solutions don't seem to work even though file is supported. Uses subst to replace newlines with \n, then echoes them back. This is more robust than doing it by hand since it allows nesting of multiline variables.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you export the variable to the shell and reference it as a shell variable, rather than a make variable, you will have better luck:

```
define VAR1
    /dev d 755 - - - - -
endef

define VAR2
    /test d 777 - - - - -
    /test2 d 777 - - - - -
endef

define VARS
$(VAR1)
$(VAR2)
endef
export VARS

all:
    echo "$$VARS" > test
```

Note the following adjustments to your makefile:

- I used `define` to create `VARS`, rather than a series of `+=` assignments, which makes it easier to get a newline between the value of `VAR1` and `VAR2`.
- I added `export VARS` to your makefile, to get the variable pushed into the environment for the shell invocation.
- I used `$$VARS` rather than `$(VARS)` to dereference it -- that leaves the expansion to the shell, rather than to make, which will avoid the "Unterminated quoted string" error.

Comment: How could I have missed that? +1

Comment: One small caveat that I regularly encounter (but always forget): this does work in recipes but not within `$(shell ...)` functions. Somehow that eats all the newlines even on output.

Answer (score 20):

GNU make 4.0 adds [the ability to write files directly](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Function.html#File-Function):

```
define VAR1
    /dev d 755 - - - - -
endef

define VAR2
    /test d 777 - - - - -
    /test2 d 777 - - - - -
endef

define VARS :=
$(VAR1)
$(VAR2)
endef

all:
        $(file > test,$(VARS))
```

Note that you still need to use `define` to define `VARS`, or the last line of `VAR1` and the first line of `VAR2` will be glommed onto one line.  Also, don't put a space after the comma in the `$(file ...)` construct, or there will be a leading space in the output!

Comment: Thanks for this - exactly what I needed to know at this time, as I hit the command line argument limitation on Windows, breaking my `make` build... This helps as there are no calls to the shell to pass parameters. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

It looks as if you're getting "Unterminated quoted string" because Make executes each line of the recipe in a separate shell, and the first line is:

```
echo "    /dev d 755 - - - - -
```

Here's the best solution I could come up with (and I admit it's not very good, but you're going against the grain of Make) is to pass `VARS` to a sub-Make which invokes `$(info ...)`:

Makefile:

```
define VAR1
    /dev d 755 - - - - -
endef

define VAR2
    /test d 777 - - - - -
    /test2 d 777 - - - - -
endef

define VARS
$(VAR1)
$(VAR2)
endef

export VARS

all:
       $(MAKE) -f Makefile.print > test
```

Makefile.print:

```
$(info $(VARS))

.PHONY:all
all:
        @# do nothing
```