# Multi-line echo in makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I'm trying to do simple c++ class generator in makefile (depending on given name), but it's really annoying when i don't know bash, and how those things work.

```
class:
    @echo "Type class name: "; \
    read CLASS_NAME; \
    echo Creating class called $${CLASS_NAME}; \
    echo "Class $${CLASS_NAME} {
    int x;
    int y;
    };">./$${CLASS_NAME}.h
```

How can I make the last echo work? I don't know how to echo multiple lines.

Comment: Out of curiosity -- did you actually set `SHELL` such that your makefile launches bash when it's running a shell command, or is it using `/bin/sh` (as it does by default)?

Comment: My bad, it should be shell as you said.

Comment: Duplicate of [Output multiline variable to a file with GNU Make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281395/output-multiline-variable-to-a-file-with-gnu-make), I believe. The referenced question has an elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslashes here are evaluated **by make**, not by the shell it invokes. (Similarly, `make` removes the newlines itself, instead of passing them to the shell).

The easiest thing to do here is to use a `printf` format string to insert your newlines rather than trying to make them literal:

```
class:
        @echo "Type class name: "; \
        read CLASS_NAME; \
        echo "Creating class called $${CLASS_NAME}"; \
        printf '%s\n' "Class $${CLASS_NAME} {" 'int x;' 'int y;' '};' >"./$${CLASS_NAME}.h"
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that works as i wanted! To be honest, i hadn't thought that i can use printf here.

Comment: `printf` is actually more portable than `echo`; see the APPLICATION USAGE section of the [POSIX standard for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), describing how and why to use `printf` instead.