# How to send input on stdin to a python script defined inside a Makefile?

Tags: python, linux, bash, variables, makefile

Given this question answer, [Embed Python in Makefile to set make variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125269/embed-python-in-makefile-to-set-make-variables) which works!

```
define NEWLINE


endef

define PYTHON_SCRIPT_CODE
import sys
print("hi")
endef

SDK_PATH := $(shell echo \
    '$(subst $(NEWLINE),@NEWLINE@,${PYTHON_SCRIPT_CODE})' | \
    sed 's/@NEWLINE@/\n/g' | python -)

default:
    @echo 'SDK Path Detected: $(SDK_PATH)'
```

How to pipe data to python std in? For example:

```
define PYTHON_SCRIPT_CODE
import sys
print("hi")
print(sys.stdin.read())
endef

# pseudocode
SDK_PATH := $(shell bash --version | PYTHON_SCRIPT_CODE)
default:
    @echo 'SDK Path Detected: $(SDK_PATH)'
```

Would output:

```
SDK Path Detected: hi
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

---

For now, I am doing this:

```
define NEWLINE


endef

BASH_VERSION := $(shell bash --version)
define PYTHON_SCRIPT_CODE
import sys
print("Hi")
print("${BASH_VERSION}")
endef

SDK_PATH := $(shell echo \
    '$(subst $(NEWLINE),@NEWLINE@,${PYTHON_SCRIPT_CODE})' | \
    sed 's/@NEWLINE@/\n/g' | python -)

default:
    @echo 'SDK Path Detected: $(SDK_PATH)'
```

Results: (No new lines)

[image]

---

Related questions:

1. [Is it possible to create a multi-line string variable in a Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649246/is-it-possible-to-create-a-multi-line-string-variable-in-a-makefile)
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222911/using-embedded-python-script-in-makefile

---

New example, without piping things into the Python Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
ECHOCMD:=/bin/echo -e
SHELL := /bin/bash

define NEWLINE


endef

VERSION := $(shell bash --version)

# With this, you cannot use single quotes inside your python code
define PYTHON_VERSION_CODE
import re, sys;
program_version = """${VERSION}"""
match = re.search("Copyright[^\d]+(\d+)", program_version);

if match:
    if int( match.group(1) ) >= 2018:
        sys.stdout.write("1")
    else:
        sys.stdout.write( match.group(1) )
else:
    sys.stdout.write("0")
endef

# Due to this, you cannot use single quotes inside your python code
PYTHON_SCRIPT_RESULTS := $(shell echo \
    '$(subst $(NEWLINE),@NEWLINE@,${PYTHON_VERSION_CODE})' | \
    sed 's/@NEWLINE@/\n/g' | python -)

all:
    printf 'Results: %s\n' "${PYTHON_SCRIPT_RESULTS}"
```

Results:

[image]

1. [Makefile as an executable script with shebang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123241/makefile-as-an-executable-script-with-shebang)

Comment: Can the solution be restricted to GNUmake or do you need a "portable" version?

Comment: Any solution you can think of is very welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the easiest way to circumvent all the command line quoting problems is to write the code to a file with GNUmake's `$(file )` function. You can even use `#` as Python comment inside of `define`d variables:

```
VERSION := $(shell bash --version)

# With this, you can use any form of quotes inside your python code
define PYTHON_VERSION_CODE :=
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
import re, sys;
program_version = "${VERSION}"
match = re.search("Copyright[^\d]+(\d+)", program_version);

if match:
    if int( match.group(1) ) >= 2018:
        sys.stdout.write("1")
    else:
        sys.stdout.write( "match:" + match.group(1) )
else:
    sys.stdout.write("0")
endef


$(file > test.py,$(PYTHON_VERSION_CODE))

PYTHON_SCRIPT_RESULTS := $(shell python test.py)

.PHONY: all
all:
    @echo $(PYTHON_SCRIPT_RESULTS)
```