# How do you create and use multi-line string variables in NMake?

Tags: makefile, nmake

I am writing an NMake build script for Windows.  I want to write a multiline string in the NMake makefile.

The approach suggested in the following question works in GNUMake, but when I use it in NMake, I get syntax errors indicating that NMake is trying to parse every line as syntax rather than as a literal string variable.

[Is it possible to create a multi-line string variable in a Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/649246/1407170)

Eventually what I want to do with the multiline string is to print it out to a file.

How do you do this in NMake (create a multiline string and echo it to a file)?

Answer (score 0):

NMake "inline files" seem to do the job for my use case:

```
@echo <<filename.txt
blah
blah
blah
<<KEEP
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/inline-files-in-a-makefile