# How to keep newline intact in a sed command used in Makefile (POSIX)?

Tags: sed, makefile, escaping, posix, newline

*Note: This is not a duplicate of [Is it possible to create a multi-line string variable in a Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649246/is-it-possible-to-create-a-multi-line-string-variable-in-a-makefile) and other such questions. This question requests POSIX compliant solutions that do not depend Bash-only or GNU Make-only features. The other question on Stack Overflow does not have this requirement.*

Take this shell script using the BSD `sed` on macOS High Sierra:

```
printf 'foo\nbaz\n' | sed '/foo/a\
bar
'
```

The output is:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

How can I put the same thing in a `Makefile`? Here is what I tried but it does not seem to work:

```
all:
    printf 'foo\nbaz\n' | sed '/foo/a\\
    bar\
    '
```

This leads to errors:

```
$ make
printf 'foo\nbaz\n' | sed '/foo/a\\
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I write the above `sed` invocation correctly in a Makefile such that when `make` executes the `all` target it feeds the trailing slash and the newlines correctly to the shell?

Note: I would like the `Makefile` to be POSIX compliant and use only features from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html.

Comment: @tripleee This is not a duplicate of the question you have linked to. If you read this question, it specifically says I want a POSIX compliant solution. The solution in the question you have linked to uses `define` which is not defined in POSIX make.

Comment: Have you tried multiple `-e` ?  You can often get away with things like this `printf 'foo\nbaz\n' | sed -e '/foo/{a\' -e 'bar' -e 'a\' -e 'bar2' -e'}'` ... unsure if helpful with your sed.  Each `-e` implies a newline of sorts though it's finicky with append.

Comment: @stevesliva Using `-e` to imply newline is not POSIX. It did not work with BSD sed on mac. The POSIX requires `-e` argument to be complete editing command. So when I try your command on Mac, I get error: `": undefined label 'ar'`. BSD sed thinks `-e 'bar'` as the `b` (branch) command with `ar` label. It didn't work. Each `-e` implying a newline of sorts is very much GNU behavior. it is not POSIX behavior. Add `--posix` argument to your sed command, then it will not work on Linux too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Parameter Expansion with Suffix Removal in `sed`

Here is a solution that puts `<newline>x` (i.e., newline followed by the character `x`) in a variable and then uses this variable in the `sed` command. While using this variable, we use [shell parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) to get rid of the `x` suffix, so that we are only left with a newline.

```
all:
    NX=$$(printf '\nx'); printf 'foo\nbaz\n' | sed "/foo/a\\$${NX%x}bar$${NX%x}"
```

The value of `NX` is `<newline>x`, so `${NX%x}` evaluates to just `<newline>`. Here is the output:

```
$ make
NX=$(printf '\nx'); printf 'foo\nbaz\n' | sed "/foo/a\\${NX%x}bar${NX%x}"
foo
bar
baz
```

#### Simplifying Parameter Expansion in `sed` with `make` Macros

We can simplify the usage of the previous solution with [`make` macros](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html#tag_20_76_13_05). We put all the unwieldy parts into macros. Then we expand those macros in the shell commands. Here is an example:

```
NX = NX=$$(printf '\nx')
NL = $${NX%x}

all:
    $(NX); printf 'foo\nbaz\n' | sed "/foo/a\\$(NL)bar$(NL)"
```

Here is the output:

```
$ make
NX=$(printf '\nx'); printf 'foo\nbaz\n' | sed "/foo/a\\${NX%x}bar${NX%x}"
foo
bar
baz
```

#### Parameter Expansion with Suffix Removal Before `sed`

Here is another possible solution on similar lines. Instead of writing the unwiedly syntax of `${NX%x}` within the `sed` command twice, it is simplified by assigning `${NX%x}` itself to another shell variable named `NL` and `${NL}` is used instead in the `sed` command.

```
all:
    NX=$$(printf '\nx'); NL=$${NX%x}; printf 'foo\nbaz\n' | sed "/foo/a\\$${NL}bar$${NL}"
```

Here is the output:

```
$ make
NX=$(printf '\nx'); NL=${NX%x}; printf 'foo\nbaz\n' | sed "/foo/a\\${NL}bar${NL}"
foo
bar
baz
```

#### Simplifying Parameter Expansion Before `sed` with `make` Macros

The usage of the above solution can be simplified further with `make` macros as follows:

```
NX = NX=$$(printf '\nx'); NL=$${NX%x}
NL = $${NL}

all:
     $(NX); printf 'foo\nbaz\n' | sed "/foo/a\\$(NL)bar$(NL)"
```

Here is the output:

```
$ make
NX=$(printf '\nx'); NL=${NX%x}; printf 'foo\nbaz\n' | sed "/foo/a\\${NL}bar${NL}"
foo
bar
baz
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't except by writing your recipe in a separate shell script and calling that instead of open-coding it in a make recipe.