# Make 3.82 - write multiple parametric lines to file

Tags: makefile, sh

I need to write multiple parametric lines to a file via make. I've tried using this:

```
param1 = param1.h 
param2 = param2.h

define multiline_param
        #include <$(1)>

        #include <$(2)>
endef


 echo "$$(call multiline_param,$(param1),$(param2))" > file.c
```

but it writes an empty line. how can I make it work? I can't use the file function since it's not included in make 3.82

Comment: What you show is not a valid makefile. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is very difficult to do in make; it's not really how make was designed.  You should consider creating a separate shell script that will handle this for you and using that instead.

However, it CAN be done.  You cannot create the content in a make variable, though, because make will not handle the newlines the way you want it to.  You will have to do something like this:

```
param1 = param1.h 
param2 = param2.h

file.c: Makefile
        ( ${foreach P,param1 param2,echo '#include <$($P)>' && } : ) > $@
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer - I unfortunately had to put there other directives other include. Probably minimized that part too much in the example but I'll keep it in mind for the simpler cases!

Comment: Sorry I didn't really understand that comment.  However, it's generally not a good idea, or even really possible, to create complex source files by generating output from makefiles.  The newline handling just won't let it work.  If you need to auto-generate a complex file you should use my first suggestion: write a shell script to do it then invoke that from the makefile.  Alternatively if you have only a few tokens to replace you can write the file as `foo.in.h` or something then use `sed` to replace the tokens and write `foo.h` as a generated file.

Answer (score 3):

> it writes an empty line.

Well, yes and no.  `make` expands this ...

> ```
> echo "$$(call multiline_param,$(param1),$(param2))" > file.c
> ```

... to this shell command ...

```
echo "$(call multiline_param,param1.h,param2.h)" > file.c
```

(note the doubling of the first "`$`" in the makefile recipe).  That should be visible in `make`'s output to the terminal.  To the shell, the `$(...)` is a command substitution, and except in the highly unlikly event that you have a command in your search path named `call multiline_param,param1.h,param2.h`, it will fail.  When it does, the command substitution will expand to nothing, so `make` will indeed write an empty line to `file.c`, but it should also emit a line something like this to stderr:

```
/bin/sh: call multiline_param,param1.h,param2.h: command not found...
```

Presumably the doubling of that `$` was an error, perhaps inspired by the fact that *without* doubling it your makefile still won't do what you appear to intend.  Unescaped `$(call multiline_param,x,y)` will expand to a multi-line string, and `make` processes each line as a separate command.  The usual approach to that is to escape the physical newlines, but that does not serve you because that will cause `make` to remove the newlines, and you need to emit literal newlines to the output file.

That's a moderately difficult thing to achieve, but @MadScientist shows you one way to do it in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77900324/2402272).

Comment: You got it, also I tried using a double $ because I was using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/649462/13563379) as a reference. I figured out a workaround for a more complex multiline parametric variable, putting it in a separate answer

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround to work with more complex multiline parametric defines, using a support variable holding the `call` and exporting it. Putting it here for future reference:

```
param1 = param1.h 
param2 = param2.h
guard = GUARD

define multiline_param
#ifndef $(3)_H
#define $(3)_H

#include <$(1)>
#include <$(2)>

#endif

endef


temp = $(call multiline_param,$(param1),$(param2),$(guard))

export temp

echo "$$temp" > file.c
```

It's probably not the most elegant solution but it does the job.